# xcode build version number in shell script

Tags: iphone, ios, shell, info.plist

I have an user-defined Project setting (KEY/VALUE) like this:

```
LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER       2.2.2.2
```

In my Info.plist, I have set the bundle version (CFBundleVersion) key/value pair like this

```
Bundle version     ${LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER}
```

I am creating a shell script to do the builds for my all of my targets.  I want to fetch the value "2.2.2.2" in my script.  This is what I tried:

```
INFO_PLIST_FULL_PATH="${PROJDIR}/${TARGET_NAME}-Info.plist"
echo plist path ${INFO_PLIST_FULL_PATH}

TARGET_BUILD_VERSION_NUMBER=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print ${BUILD_NUMBER}" $INFO_PLIST_FULL_PATH)
echo version_number ${TARGET_BUILD_VERSION_NUMBER}
```

When I do this, the output for plist path is correct but TARGET_BUILD_VERSION_NUMBER output is "${LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER}" instead of "2.2.2.2"

How can I get the value instead of the variable name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode doesn't substitute the value till it copies over the file into the built product. So, go to the source: Grab the value out of the *.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file. You should be able to find the current value in there with a quick search. Then you just have to devise a regex to strip it out.

Comment: Actually, in the script, i am doing the xcodebuild command first and then trying to look for this info.  I need this info to create a directory within for each build number to save the .ipa files into.  the process is xcodebuild->find version->create directory->packageApplication into that directory.  Shouldn't the files be copied over by then?

Comment: The file will be inside the *.app/Contents/ directory. The easiest way to work with this would be to add a Run Script build phase, because then you get access to a bunch of great Xcode build variables like [`$TARGET_BUILD_DIR`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW88).